# The successive minima of a lattice

Tags: lattice-crypto

I am new to lattice theory. I hope(will be grateful) that one could explain to me this claim 7 in REGEV course(this claim appears in this file page 6 : [https://cims.nyu.edu/~regev/teaching/lattices_fall_2004/ln/introduction.pdf](https://cims.nyu.edu/%7Eregev/teaching/lattices_fall_2004/ln/introduction.pdf)) which states that :
The successive minima of a lattice are achieved i.e., for every 1 ≤ i ≤ n, there exists a vector
vi ∈ Λ with ‖v_{i}‖ = λi(Λ).

Thank you,

Answer (score 6):

> **Claim 7**: The successive minima of a lattice are achieved i.e., for every $1 \leq i \leq n$, there exists a vector $v_i \in \Lambda$ with $\lVert v_{i}\rVert = \lambda_i(\Lambda)$.

There is a proof of that claim

> **Proof:** By Corollary 6, the ball of radius (say) $2\lambda_i(\Lambda)$ contains only finitely many lattice points. It follows
> from the definition of $\lambda_i$ that one of these vectors must have length $\lambda_i(\Lambda)$.

This suggests we should look at two places

> **Corollary 6**: Let $\Lambda$
> be a lattice. Then there exists some $\epsilon > 0$
> such that $\lVert x − y\rVert > \epsilon$
> for any two
> non-equal lattice points $x, y \in\Lambda$.

> **Definition 7**: Let $\Lambda$ be a lattice of rank $n$. For $i \in \{1, \dots , n\}$ we define the $i$th successive minimum as
> $\lambda_i(\Lambda) = \inf \{r \mid \dim(\mathsf{span}(\Lambda ∩ \overline{B}(0, r))) \geq i\}$
> where $\overline{B}(0, r) = \{x \in\mathbb{R}^m \mid \lVert x\rVert \leq r\}$ is the closed ball of radius $r$ around $0$.

How does this proof follow?
Consider $\overline{B}(0, \lambda_i(\Lambda))\cap \Lambda$.
By definition, this contains at least $i$ linearly independent lattice vectors (and is the smallest ball such that this occurs).
This is to say that shrinking the ball leads to a set containing *at most* $i-1$ linearly independent lattice vectors, i.e. the $i$th linearly independent lattice vector is on the surface of this ball.

Why does the claim state

> the ball of radius (say) $2\lambda_i(Λ)$R contains only finitely many lattice points $\dots$

$\lambda_i(\Lambda)$ is defined with an *infimum*.
This is an "infinite" version of $\min$ (similarly to how $\sup$ is an "infinite" version of $\max$).
In particular, it is important to know that for a sequence $a_i$, $\inf a_i = a$ does **not** mean there is any particular index $i^*$ such that $a_{i^*} = a$.
For example, $a_i = i^{-1}$ (for $i > 0$) has an infimum of $0$ (as $i\mapsto 0^+$), but never achieves this limit.

This means that there was some risk that there is some infinite sequence of lattice points such that $\lVert \vec v_i\rVert\mapsto \lambda_i(\Lambda)$ in the limit, but there is no index $i$ such that this equality holds.
The proof handles this via noting that infimum (supremum) and min (max) agree on *finite* sets. Since we are restricting to a finite set, we can replace the $\inf$ with a $\min$, and note that it *must* be achieved by some element of the finite set.

Comment: what a great, unambiguous answer ! thanks a lot.